# Putting a border on a polygon image map?

Tags: html, css, image, dictionary, imagemap

I was wondering if it were possible to but a border on an image map?
The only answers I've found are related to putting a border on images.

The polygon I'm using is a skewed square.

Also, any suggestions as to any alternative methods to using image maps (excluding flash)?

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I can think of is mimicking image map behavior with a canvas element, but this seems like overkill.  Re: KISS, is there any reason you can't add the border to the image itself in an image editing program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be done using CSS alone, but there are JavaScript solutions. For example, the [jQuery Map Hilight Plugin](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/) works very nicely. Examples:

- [The United States of America](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html)
- [Demo of most features](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_features.html)

Comment: Thanks, the demos are great! :]